# Convert numeric data in text file to dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, text

I have a text file which is consisted of this:

```
20 23
0 16
1 2
1 6
1 7
1 8
2 11
2 16
2 17
3 14
3 16
3 17
4 7
4 13
4 17
```

and i need it to in a python dict like this:

```
{0:[16],1:[2,6,7,8],2:[11,16,17],3:[14,16,17],4:[7,13,17],20:[23]}
```

thanks

Comment: You can use `csv` module to read your data and a `collections.defaultsict()` to create your expected dictionary. But it's better to add your code and tell us what's the problem with your code?

Comment: @Kasramvd did you mean `defaultdict()`?

Comment: @BlackVegetable NO :-) `defaultsict` is a python [Easter egg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easter_egg_(media)). It can give you a dictionary with any format that you want. But never use it! because it can cause your computer to blown away lol.

Comment: @Kasramvd ah, but of course. I forgot about that one! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `collections.defaultdict` for this.

Complete example below.

```
import csv
from io import StringIO
from collections import defaultdict

mystr = StringIO("""20 23
0 16
1 2
1 6
1 7
1 8
2 11
2 16
2 17
3 14
3 16
3 17
4 7
4 13
4 17
""")

d = defaultdict(list)

# replace mystr with open('file.csv', 'r')
with mystr as f:
    for i, j in csv.reader(f, delimiter=' '):
        d[int(i)].append(int(j))
```

Result:

```
print(d)

defaultdict(list,
            {0: [16],
             1: [2, 6, 7, 8],
             2: [11, 16, 17],
             3: [14, 16, 17],
             4: [7, 13, 17],
             20: [23]})
```

Answer (score 1):

Without claiming that this is the most efficient way (this is just the one that comes in my mind) I would do this:

```
my_dict = {}
with open('input_file_name', 'r') as input_file:
    for line in input_file:
        line = line.strip()
        key = line.split(' ')[0]
        value = line.split(' ')[1]
        my_dict[key] = my_dict.get(key, [])
        my_dict[key].append(value)
```

And to print the dictionary:

```
for key, value in my_dict.items():
    print (key, value)
```

output:

```
4 ['7', '13', '17']
2 ['11', '16', '17']
20 ['23']
1 ['2', '6', '7', '8']
3 ['14', '16', '17']
0 ['16']
```

Dictionaries are not sorted though. 
You can however sort the dictionary when you print it:

```
for key,value in sorted(my_dict.items(), key=lambda x: int(x[0])):
    print (key, value)
```

Please ask me if you need specifications on what each line means!

Answer (score 0):

you better use pandas,

lets assume you have the data in an excel datasheet

[image]

The directory to this excel file is

```
path = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\python\excel.xlsx"

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(path)

dictionary = df.groupby("key")["value"].apply(list).to_dict()

print(dictionary)

{0: [16], 1: [2, 6, 7, 8], 2: [11, 16, 17], 3: [14, 16, 17], 4: [7, 13, 17], 20: [23]}
```